# Fallback Route config in Kong

Tags: kong, fallback, kong-ingress

I am trying to create a Fallback Route in my K8s application. I have a Pod serving a fallback app that returns a 404 page on URL http://domain:80/error. It works fine if I call http://application/error but fails as soon as I call http://application/test or http://application/dummy or http://application/error-page123, It returns Kong 404 page.

I want to route all the non-existed routes to /error, How can I achieve this.

My 404 Config -

```
  - name: con-404
  url: http://con-404:80/error-page
  routes:
  - name: con-404
    paths:
    - /error-page.*
    hosts:
    - '{{ .Values.domainName }}'
    preserve_host: true
    strip_path: true
```

Logs:

```
    72.16.3.236 - - [15/Dec/2021:16:33:12 +0000] "GET /_next/static/chunks/19e98d60.b3e7ae89433b365ce824.js HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "https://atul.aws-domain.com/error-page123" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
172.16.3.236 - - [15/Dec/2021:16:33:12 +0000] "GET /_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-0e21341ffcede83f5f91.js HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "https://atul.aws-domain.com/error-page123" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
172.16.3.236 - - [15/Dec/2021:16:33:12 +0000] "GET /_next/static/37136da7f9f13c7143c0ab3fbca0b705e051674e/_buildManifest.js HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "https://atul.aws-domain.com/error-page123" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
172.16.3.236 - - [15/Dec/2021:16:33:12 +0000] "GET /_next/static/chunks/47b02e17009e033f7403a15a7895e4e8f1a7e0a0.b42e815d27210619a63a.js HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "https://atul.aws-domain.com/error-page123" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
172.16.3.236 - - [15/Dec/2021:16:33:12 +0000] "GET /_next/static/37136da7f9f13c7143c0ab3fbca0b705e051674e/_ssgManifest.js HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "https://atul.aws-domain.com/error-page123" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
172.16.3.236 - - [15/Dec/2021:16:33:12 +0000] "GET /_next/static/chunks/pages/error-page-89e06fc8f15977bfc559.js HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "https://atul.aws-domain.com/error-page123" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
172.16.3.236 - - [15/Dec/2021:16:33:12 +0000] "GET /fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "https://atul.aws-domain.com/error-page123" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
172.16.3.236 - - [15/Dec/2021:16:33:12 +0000] "GET /fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "https://atul.aws-domain.com/error-page123" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
172.16.3.236 - - [15/Dec/2021:16:33:12 +0000] "GET /fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "https://atul.aws-domain.com/error-page123" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
2021/12/15 16:33:12 [debug] 1098#0: *3062 [lua] init.lua:973: balancer(): setting address (try 1): 10.100.7.138:80
2021/12/15 16:33:12 [debug] 1098#0: *3062 [lua] init.lua:1002: balancer(): enabled connection keepalive (pool=10.100.7.138|80, pool_size=60, idle_timeout=60, max_requests=100)
172.16.3.236 - - [15/Dec/2021:16:33:12 +0000] "GET /error-page/favicons/favicon-32x32.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2090 "https://atul.aws-domain.com/error-page123" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"e
```

Comment: Have you followed https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/2.6.x/reference/proxy/#configuring-a-fallback-route ?

Comment: yes, I have tried, but if the path does not exist, it displays the kong 404 page.

Comment: can you share your configuration and the result of a curl with kong debug set to 1 ?

Comment: Update the config and logs in question, I do not see the logs specific to the upstream URL which is being called (should be ../error-page) .

Comment: There is no fallback in your configuration something catching all path: `"paths": ["/"],`

Comment: even adding that is also not helping.

Comment: What curl with kong debug set to 1 highlight as the matched route and service ?